# Change decimaPrecision value of numberfield after rendering

Tags: extjs

I have currency drop down and amount number field.on select of currency the value of amount field should get formatted with decimal precision value and this deciam precision should be changed in currency select value.
Ex: Currency:"AED",
then amount value should be fromatted with 12.00(2 decimal presion)
Currency:"USD",
then amount value should be fromatted with 12.000(3 decimal presion)
so,i want decimal precison value change dynamically

Answer (score 0):

In the select event of currency combo, you can try by changing the value of decimalPrecision of amount numberfield in the following way:

```
select:function(combo, record){
 Ext.getCmp('id of amount field').decimalPrecision = record[0].data.dP;
}
```

Here, dP is the value present in the your currency record, for example, for AED dP is 2 and for USD dP is 3.

Hope this helps.

PS: Solution not tested for all browsers.